# Remove characters before and including _ and calculate

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

If i have a dataframe like this:

```
id    floor
01      2
02     1-2
03      
04     -1
```

How can i get the total number of floors by removing string before and including _? Thanks.

```
 id   Totalfloor
01      1
02      2
03      
04      1
```

Comment: What are your suggestions? what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I see no underscores in your data.  In your example please explain how floor `2` maps to Totalfloor `1`, floor `1-2` maps to Totalfloor `2`, and floor `-1` maps to Totalfloor `1`.

Comment: Not too much. But I would like to remove characters before and including _  as first step, because there are many rows indicate floors as 1-2, 1-3, etc.

Comment: @ahbon:  Okay, but then why does your example include zero underscores?  If that's something you want help with why don't you show it in your data?  And what meaning does NUMBER DASH NUMBER have?  How are you making calculations from it?  You want help but you are keeping your assumptions in your head and out of your question.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of minus signs in front of your floor numbers use :

`df['floor'] = df['floor'].abs()`

This will turn all values into absolute values.

I'm not sure how you count 1-2 floors? Do you, if it says 1 to 2, always assume the higher number as in 2?

Comment: It says from first floor to the second floor. Thanks.